# Pandas dataframe with lists to dataframe with numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
                                                  Amplitude (V)                                           Time (s)
type   board                                                                                                      
input  A      [-6.475490109651011e-05, -6.459461668784777e-0...  [-1.8824999999999998e-08, -1.8775e-08, -1.8724...
output A      [-0.00043152308693648455, 0.0, 8.6307784645449...  [-2.3625e-08, -2.3574999999999998e-08, -2.3525...
       B      [-0.00038705227067327414, -0.00111277816346858...  [-6.6025e-08, -6.597500000000001e-08, -6.5925e...
```

I want to "explode" each of these lists into numbers to get a "normal dataframe". How can I do this? Preferably without loosing information about the index.

Comment: Have you tried `df.explode` ?

Comment: `df.explode(['Time (s)','Amplitude (V)'])` is the solution, post it as an answer so I accept it. You deserve whatever credit that gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df.explode(['Time (s)','Amplitude (V)'])
```